# Why does my C Program crash when I try to delete a node out of a singe linked list

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list

I am currently creating a Program in C which is basically a linked list inside of a linked list. The inner list being character and the outer list being words. Unfortunately I'm having Problems with deleting some of the outer Nodes (words) and freeing their memory. My program keeps crashing and I have no idea why. The compiler doesnt give me any warnings or errors and I've been looking for a fix for hours. Any help is apreciated for anyone who could look over the code! Thanks!

```
*void deleteWord (Node* Node, int index){
int counter = 0;
if (Node == NULL)
    return;

while (Node->next != NULL && counter != (index - 1)){
    Node = Node->next;
    counter++;
}
struct node* wordTemp = Node->next;
//Node->next = Node->next->next;

while (wordTemp->word != NULL){
    InnerNode* letterTemp = wordTemp->word->next;
    free(wordTemp->word);
    wordTemp->word = letterTemp;
}
free(wordTemp);
return;
}
```

Comment: why `counter != (index - 1)`? Is `counter` zero-based and `index` 1-based?

Comment: so that i get the node that comes before the node that i actually wanna free, so i can link it with the one that comes after the one i wanna free

Comment: hmm ok. But if you pass in index 0 you'll get the last node in the list, probably not what you want. You need to handle corner cases too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are freeing Node->next (stored in wordTemp), without re-assigning it, essentially breaking the link in the linked list, so now Node->next points to a deleted memory.

Comment: i am linking the currrent node with the one that comes after the one i wanna delete. node->next becomes node->next->next, so esentially linking the previous node with the next one and making a copy of the one i wanna free calling it wordTemp